# Optional model property with nested required properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc

With code like the following:

```
public class FooModel {

    public BarModel Bar { get; set; }

}

public class BarModel {

    [Required]
    public string Baz { get; set; }

}
```

I want to render `FooModel.Bar` in a form, but have it be optional.  However, the form won't submit without any input in the text box for `BarModel.Baz`.  Is there a way to go about making the nested model in `FooModel` optional without having to remove the `RequiredAttribute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to go about making the nested model in FooModel
>   optional without having to remove the RequiredAttribute?

Not that I am aware of. I would recommend you using a view model which will be adapted to the requirements of your view (i.e. have the `Baz` property optional):

```
public class FooModel 
{
    public BarViewModelModel Bar { get; set; }
}

public class BarViewModelModel 
{
    public string Baz { get; set; }
}
```

That's one of the reasons why you should always use view models and never pass your domain models to the views. As you can see your domain models are not adapted to the specific requirements of the views. You could have some properties required in certain views and optional in other views.

Comment: They were both view models, but I was trying to reuse `BarModel` which was a more or less general-purpose model.  I suppose this means that reusing view models from different namespaces is also generally a bad practice?

Comment: The rule of thumb is the following: if the view model suits the requirements of the view then reuse it. This doesn't seem to be your case though.