# ASP.NET MVC - How to implement an optional nested model with required fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently in the process of implementing a form in an ASP.NET MVC4 application and I can't seem to find a good and maintainable solution concerning input validation. Given the following (simplified) model:

```
public class PersonalData
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public AddressData ResidentialAddress { get { return residentialAddress; } }
    private readonly AddressData residentialAddress = new AddressData();

    public AddressData PostalAddress { get; set; }
}

public class AddressData
{
    [Required]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int HouseNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I think that this model definition pretty much speaks for itself: I'm capable of declaring properties on the 'PersonalData'-class as 'Required', and I'm also capable of doing the same on the 'AddressData'-model. This approach works with the 'ResidentialAddress'-property, but it gets tricky however with optional nested models, such as the one provided in the 'PostalAddress'-property.

Simply put:

- All string properties on the '*PersonalData*'-model are required;
- All string properties on the '*AddressData*'-object stored in the '*ResidentialAddress*'-property are required;
- '*PostalAddress*' is optional: All string properties on the '*AddressData*'-object stored in the '*PostalAddress*'-property are required **if** an '*AddressData*'-instance was specified to it.

'Flattening out' the PersonalData-model doesn't seem like a desirable solution to me, especially considering the fact that we're using an EditorTemplate.

What are my options? Am I doing something wrong on a fundamental level? Is there a generally supported technique for this?

Comment: I'm afraid that there's no simple (straight forward) solution. At least none I can think of (or find, for that mater). Please take a look at [this (identical) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480457/optional-model-property-with-nested-required-properties). On a related note, I do prefer writing "full" models even if that means combining several business models.

Comment: This (having a separate postal address or not) goes into business logic. You won't be able to solve it declaratively. You will need to write some extra lines of code to handle this, I'm afraid...

Comment: Thomas and Andrei; thanks for your quick responses. I actually managed to find a solution which suits my needs but your remarks are definitely to be taken in consideration. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I actually found a solution that suits my need! Suppose that a controller has this method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(PersonalData model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Success
        return Redirect("NextAction");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

The instantiation of the '*PersonalData*'-object that is used in the 'model'-parameter here is based on the deserialization of the POST-variables that were being sent.

Now, if the following POST-variables were being sent:

- **FirstName**: 'John'
- **LastName**: 'Doe'
- **ResidentialAddress.ZipCode**: '1234AB'
- **ResidentialAddress.City**: 'My City'
- **ResidentialAddress.Street**: 'My Street'
- **ResidentialAddress.HouseNumber**: '123'

Then it will be serialized into a 'PersonalData'-instance, on which the 'ResidentialAddress'-property must be assigned with a valid 'AddressData'-instance. (MVC seems to take care of this automatically).

The presence of 'PostalAddress'-related POST-variables, as follows...

- **PostalAddress.ZipCode**: '1234AB'
- **PostalAddress.City**: 'My City'
- **PostalAddress.Street**: 'My Street'
- **PostalAddress.HouseNumber**: '123'

...appears to control whether or not the serialization will result in the instantiation of an 'AddressData'-instance to the 'PostalAddress'-property, which exactly covers the case that I want.

Bottom line: maintain control over what POST-variables are being sent and you should be OK! I hope this helps anyone out; suggestions and/or comments are welcome!